# Difference in Tomcat invocation context between inside and outside Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

This posting is a follow-up to an [earlier posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59603006/tomcat-application-works-with-complete-path-and-resource-not-otherwise) of mine.  I am trying to understand the difference in Tomcat execution context, depending upon whether Tomcat is invoked from within the Eclipse IDE or the OS shell.

My findings are captured in the following table:

[image]

---

The [response to the earlier posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59603006/tomcat-application-works-with-complete-path-and-resource-not-otherwise) gives a good explanation for why the Tomcat Welcome page is not accessible when Tomcat is invoked from within Eclipse.  I am now trying to understand why the webapp (`http://localhost:8080/helloworld/hello`) cannot be accessed when Tomcat is invoked outside the Eclipse IDE (i.e. from OS shell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse knows about Tomcat, and provides it with its own set of web applications, without storing them in the standalone-version's `webapps` directory. As I've said in the answer to the question you link, you can write your own ROOT application, and if eclipse would overwrite an application that's there already, you might not be too happy about it.

In order to run your helloworld application in the standalone tomcat, build a `helloworld.war` archive and deploy it to the standalone tomcat by copying it into its webapps directory.

**You're basically running two differently configured servers, even though they might share the same code and use the same port number**.